# Android Studio C++ no ejecuta división por cero

Tags: android, c++, studio

Tengo un método nativo (C++) en Android que hace que la aplicación "crashee". La instrucción que quiero que se ejecute para provocar el error y el cierre de la aplicación es la siguiente:

```
uint32_t crash = (rand % 0xFFFFFFFF) / 0.0;
```

Lo curioso es que cuando compilo para hacer el test esta linea no se ejecuta (como he comprobado depurando), el programa se la salta y no la ejecuta entiendo porque detecta que es una división por zero. Alguien sabe como puedo forzar que se ejecute y provocar el crash ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En C++ la división por 0 da infinito o **NaN** en caso de `0/0`. Lo que si provoca error es cuando haces una división de enteros `int div = 1 / 0` por ejemplo.

Comment: Eso significa que está bien hecho :P Cada vez que dividas por cero, tu líder de proyecto va a programar otra reunión de dos horas

Comment: La división entre 0 provoca una excepción aritmética, en realidad deberías evitar esta división,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una división entre cero no es un crash, es un comportamiento indefinido como puede verse en el [estándar de C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/n4917.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> ##### 7.6.5 Operadores multiplicativos
>
> 1. Los operadores multiplicativos `*`, `/` y `%` se agrupan de izquierda a derecha.
> 2. ...
> 3. ...
> 4. El operador binario `/` devuelve el cociente y el operador binario `%` devuelve el residuo de la división de la primera expresión contra la segunda. **Si el segundo operando de `/` o `%` es cero, el comportamiento es indefinido**.

Frente a un comportamiento indefinido el compilador puede decidir hacer lo que le parezca bien, por ejemplo: puede decidir no hacer nada, puede decidir dar un valor al azar, puede decidir no compilar ese código, puede decidir lanzar una excepción o puede decidir [invocar demonios en tus fosas nasales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Si quieres forzar un error prueba ejecutar un método de un objeto inexistente:

```
std::string &s = *(std::string *)(nullptr);
s.push_back('\n');
```